# Change <td> color when checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, html-table

Currently I work with twig and Symfony2.
In one of my twig files I create a table which is filled dynamically with a for loop.

So it creates several  entries that look like that:

```
<td>
<input type='checkbox' name='somename'>
</td>
```

Now i'd like the td background color to change if the checkbox is checked.
I already tried several JSFiddles i found...without success.

They all look like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/YQD7c/1/
More or less...but i can only post 1 link here.

Heres my complete table:

```
<table class="index" cellpadding="5px">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>....</th>
                <th>....</th>
                <th>....</th>
                <th>....</th>
                <th>....</th>
                <th>....</th>
                <th>....</th>
            </tr>   
            </thead>    
            <tbody>
                {% for l in list %}
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                            {{some.other.things.in.list}}
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            ...
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            ...
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ...
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            ...
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type='checkbox' name='box[{{l.id}}]'>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="...">Edit</a>
                        </td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I tried to make a `<div>` around the checkboxes and also copy and pasted the js fiddles... but nothing has worked for me.

What could be wrong?

Comment: the jsfiddle shows red when clicked on chrome. What browser you using?

Comment: It shows red for me too. Im using FF. The problem is, in my project it wont work...

Comment: you will need to be more specific if it works in chrome and FF then where doesn't it work and why?

Comment: The JS Fiddle is not my own. But i c&p it which should normaly work. But it displays no color if i check a checkbox.

Comment: where did you paste the javascript code to? did you include the css style also?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you aren't doing is linking your javascript to your HTML.

Simply copy pasting your code and the jsFiddle you posted, results to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Dnmwu/) Which works fine.

So what you might need to do is to create a script block in your html file that has the javascript to link to, either directly:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script language="javascript">
        //code here
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

or by linking a javascript file:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>    
</head>
```

Comment: Thats because of Twig ;)

My JS IS included(because of twig) like this:

{% block head %}
 {% javascripts '@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/js/some.js' %}
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> {# jQuery Libary #}
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset_url}}"></script>
 {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}

Comment: then please post a full version of your code with your javascript either in jsFiddle or here to properly understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define "id" property for `<td>` inside for loop. Then read the value of the ticked   checkbox using jquery selector and set the required color for that particular `<td>` element.